# AlertDialog disappearing after screen rotation after pressing back

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have overridden onBackPressed() method and in it I am popping up a dialog which asks for user confirmation. However upon rotating the device , the dialog disappears.

I searched on different threads here at StackOverflow which mention that use DialogFragment or override onCreateDialog() and onPrepareDialog() methods for the activity and then call showDialog(id) to display the dialog.

Now , my question is how will I handle the onBackPressed method in the case if I use onCreateDialog and onPrepareDialog ?

Earlier I was doing dialog.show() in onBackPressed. What do I do now ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to save your ui state.

Add a member `private boolean mIsConfirmationDialogShowing = false;` to your activity and set it when you display the dialog.

Make sure you store the value of this in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in `onCreate()`.

Then in `onResume()`, display the confirmation dialog again if `mIsConfirmationDialogShowing` is set.

Set it to `false` on cancel.

Comment: So you mean to say that is `mIsConfirmationDialogShowing` is set then I need to create the whole dialog and show it again ?

Comment: Correct. Just place the creation into a separate method, and you can call it from `onBackPressed()` and `onResume()`

Answer (score -2):

The answer is call method [showDialog()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int%29). But this method is deprecated, and google recommend to use DialogFragment